# Make a GUI neater programmatically?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I am currently developing a program for an organization who takes care of foster children. Their old solution is outdated and unsupported so they wanted a new system that could take of the management part of things.

What I need help with here, is how to make one GUI I made by generating it, look as close as possible to a GUI I made by hand.

Here you see a GUI I made by hand:

[image: GUI]

Here is the same GUI made with programming:

[image: Programming GUI]

As you can see there is a clear difference in how tight the GUI looks. The one generated also looks different because they wanted all fields editable (a reason why I had to change how I made the GUI).

I make the GUI by interpreting a simple XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <gui groupboxlabel="Barnets Stamdata" type="CHILD">
        <textbox label="CPR" />
        <textbox label="Navn" />
        <textbox label="Efternavn" />
        <textbox label="Addresse" />
        <textbox label="Hus nr." />
        <textbox label="Opgang" />
        <textbox label="Post Nr." />
        <textbox label="By" />
        <textbox label="Email" />
        <textbox label="Telefon nr." />
        <textbox label="Sagsbehandler" />
        <textbox label="Konsulent" />
        <textbox label="Aflastning" />
        <combobox label="Foranstaltning" />
        <datetimepicker label="Anbring" />
        <datetimepicker label="Udskriv" />
    </gui>
</root>
```

I would like to know how I make the generated GUI neater and more compact like the first I did by hand in the IDE? Or as close possible at least. I already set the Margin property to 0;0;0;0 between Controls in the FlowLayout that all the Controls go in.

But can I reduce the distance between the Controls even more so they come closer together?

Here is a side by side comparison just to make it clear how much of a difference there is:

[image: side by side]

**EDIT**

As requested, the code that creates the controls:

```
public GroupBox CreateNewView(String path, String token)
        {
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load(path);

            DataBag info = Facade.GetFosterChild(EIdentifierType.CPR, token);

            XmlNodeList nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes(@"/root/gui");
            GroupBox gb = new GroupBox();
            foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
            {
                gb.Text = node.Attributes["groupboxlabel"].Value;
                gb.AutoSize = true;

                FlowLayoutPanel panel = new FlowLayoutPanel();
                panel.AutoSize = true;
                panel.WrapContents = true;
                panel.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown;
                panel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                panel.Padding = new Padding(0, 0, 0, 0);

                for (int i = 0; i < node.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
                {
                    XmlNode child = node.ChildNodes.Item(i);
                    switch (child.Name)
                    {
                        case "textbox":
                            String txtlabel = child.Attributes["label"].Value;
                            TextBoxControl txtctrl = new TextBoxControl(txtlabel);
                            txtctrl.Content = (String)info.Data[i];
                            txtctrl.SetDisplay((String)info.Data[i]);
                            panel.Controls.Add(txtctrl);
                            panel.Width = txtctrl.Width;
                            break;
                        case "combobox":
                            String combolabel = child.Attributes["label"].Value;
                            ComboBoxControl comboctrl = new ComboBoxControl(combolabel, (String[])info.Data[i]);
                            comboctrl.Content = (String[])info.Data[i];
                            comboctrl.SetDisplay(0);
                            panel.Controls.Add(comboctrl);
                            panel.Width = comboctrl.Width;
                            break;
                        case "datetimepicker":
                            String datelabel = child.Attributes["label"].Value;
                            DateTimeControl datectrl = new DateTimeControl(datelabel, (DateTime)info.Data[i]);
                            panel.Controls.Add(datectrl);
                            panel.Width = datectrl.Width;
                            break;
                        case "#comment":
                            break;
                        default:
                            Console.WriteLine("No Tag Found");
                            break;
                    }
                }
                gb.Controls.Add(panel);
            }
            return gb;
        }
```

**EDIT 2**

Adding another snippet of code as requested. Put it in a Pastebin link because there is a bit much :S

http://pastebin.com/qtPRLgNK

Comment: `I make the GUI by interpreting a simple XML file` - So, you're trying to reinvent WPF, but on winforms. Why not just use WPF instead, which BTW also supports customization, styling and theming?

Comment: Personally, I think the one on the right looks better. If you want more/less margin then just set it programmatically. You really need to specify what framework you're using as well (WPF or WinForms?)

Comment: @EdS. That sure *looks* like WinForms

Comment: @HighCore Because when I started making this project I did it in WinForms and the customer suddenly wants things done pretty fast. So I can't really redo all the code I got already in WPF. There is also the problem that I never worked with WPF so getting to know that now, would be pretty bad timing.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: Agreed, but speaking as someone who doesn't do UI work for a living, my WPF UI's typically look a lot like WinForms as well :D Regardless, it should be tagged properly.

Comment: @EdS. Sorry for not clarifying. It's winforms.

Comment: @Vipar I don't see any code about how you create your controls from your xml. how can we help you?

Comment: @Vipar, you should read about the [Sunk Cost fallacy](http://youarenotsosmart.com/2011/03/25/the-sunk-cost-fallacy/).

Comment: You can use `new Margin(-2, -2, -2, -2)` on the controls

Comment: @DourHighArch I know about that fallacy. But this is not the case. It's not because I don't want to, it's because time constraints make it impossible for me to migrate within the given deadline. The customer will not negotiate it at this time :/

Comment: @YoryeNathan Margin is not a class. Did you mean Padding? Should I use it on the controls or the flowlayout?

Comment: Yeah I think I meant `Padding`, and on the controls.

Comment: @YoryeNathan Not possible. Can't be lower than 0.

Comment: I recall playing with negative numbers of Margin/Padding. Not near VS right now, though. Either way, you can just not use `FlowLayoutPanel` and position the controls yourself, as it is done in a pretty simple fashion. What's `TextBoxControl` anyways? A wrapper around the `TextBox` control could be "adding" irremovable space.

Comment: @YoryeNathan Did you read the question at all..?

Comment: @YoryeNathan It says that I need to make it programmatically, but you say that I should try and place it myself..? Sounded like you didn't read the question proper :/

Comment: Doing something yourself doesn't mean you do it in the designer, it means you don't use something that does it for you. Place your controls using *your own logic* instead of `FlowLayoutPanel`, *through code*

Comment: Where do you set the ( at least Top & Bottom) Margin to zero for the content controls..??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controls come with a default `Margin` of (3, 3, 3, 3). In addition to the zero `Padding` of the `FLP` you should set the Controls' `Margins` to zero or values you like:

```
switch (child.Name)
{
    case "textbox":
        String txtlabel = child.Attributes["label"].Value;
        TextBoxControl txtctrl = new TextBoxControl(txtlabel);
        txtctrl.Content = (String)info.Data[i];
        txtctrl.SetDisplay((String)info.Data[i]);
        txtctrl.Margin = new Padding(1, 1, 1, 1); // <---- or whatever you like
        panel.Controls.Add(txtctrl);
        panel.Width = txtctrl.Width;
        break;
    case "combobox":
        String combolabel = child.Attributes["label"].Value;
        ComboBoxControl comboctrl = new ComboBoxControl(combolabel,
                                                       (String[])info.Data[i]);
        comboctrl.Content = (String[])info.Data[i];
        comboctrl.SetDisplay(0);
        comboctrl.Margin = new Padding(1, 1, 1, 1); // <----  or whatever you like
        panel.Controls.Add(comboctrl);
        panel.Width = comboctrl.Width;
        break;
    case "datetimepicker":
        String datelabel = child.Attributes["label"].Value;
        DateTimeControl datectrl = new DateTimeControl(datelabel,
                                                      (DateTime)info.Data[i]);
        datectrl.Margin = new Padding(1, 1, 1, 1); // <----  or whatever you like
        panel.Controls.Add(datectrl);
        panel.Width = datectrl.Width;
        break;
    case "#comment":
        break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("No Tag Found");
        break;
}
```

**Upadte:**

As your `Controls` are actually `UserControls`, make sure they either

- Are `Autosize = true` and **all** embedded `Controls` have a zero `Margin`
- ..or they are `Autosize = false` and have they **minimum** `Height` necessary to hold them all.

You Image shows a gap of `4` pixels. This is a hint that not the default margin height of 2x 3 pixels is the culprit but a wrong `UserControl.Height` or 2x 2 pixels.

Comment: I set the Margin to 0;0;0;0 in every individual control that is created.

Comment: Meaning what? Does it help? (There is no such setting in the code you have posted..)

Comment: I thought I mentioned it..? Either way, the individual controls have their Margin set to 0;0;0;0 (in their own code, which is not posted) so I didn't have to do that when I generated the GUI.

Comment: No, I didn't understand that. could you post at least one of the classes? what type do they have? UserControl? FLP? I suspect that one of the containers still does have a positive Margin set!

Comment: Sure, I'll post one of them. The class extends UserControl yes. The Margin is set through the property editor in Visual Studio. :)

Comment: OK, there is no Margin set in that code either. You wrote that you set in in the  property editor, so it is in the Desgner.cs. But: do set the Margins for for __all__ parts? That is for the UC and the (presumably) embedded Controls? Your image shows a space of four pixels, which is not the default margin of 3 or 2x3 pixels.. A short no frills test shows that controls in a flp can easily sit along each other without any space.

Comment: Hm. You might have the point there actually. I put Margin to 0 on the Control and not the buttons, fields and label...that could be it, let me try real quick.

Comment: Now I set the Margin to 0 on all components and the gap is still there :/

Comment: Hm. How do you set the Height of the UCs? Can you reduce it by 2 pixels? Or are they AutoSize=true?

Comment: They are AutoSize is false.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69994/discussion-between-taw-and-vipar).

Comment: Thanks for the chat. Here is your Accepted Answer :)